# Can't Run C# SharpPcap Program Under User Account

Tags: c#, sharppcap, packetdotnet

I code a C# program to catch and resolve packets using **SharpPcap** and **PacketDotNet**. It performs well when I run it  in Administrator Account, still it will popup a window as below:

*The question means"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?*
[image: The question means"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?".]

However, when I log in with an Normal User account and run the program, it will faile and catch some exceptions:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SharpPcap.PcapException: 慐正瑥敇䅴慤瑰牥慎敭㩳䌠畯摬❮⁴敧⁴牥潲⁲敭獳条⁥潦⁲牥潲⁲㘨㘲㤱㈴㈷)�岔ⶵ
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDeviceList.GetDevices()
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDeviceList.Refresh()
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDeviceList..ctor()
at SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDeviceList.get_Instance()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

So, I try to run it as Administrator Identity under the Normal User account. I find out the program can run without any exception!

I really got confused with this situation. I want to know how can I run it with a normal user account and it doesn't catch exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely reason is Npcap “Admin-only Mode”

From https://npcap.com/guide/index.html

> Npcap supports restricting its use to Administrators for safety purpose. If Npcap is installed with the option “Restrict Npcap driver's access to Administrators only” checked, only Built-in Administrators may access its features via user software (Nmap, Wireshark, etc). This provides a level of restriction similar to requiring root access for packet capture on Linux/UNIX.

Comment: I read the document from https://npcap.com/ and found the answer! I tried to uninstall the existed Npcap and reinstall it without checking the  “Restrict Npcap driver's access to Administrators only” option. It works! Thank you so much!